# While adding Jar file in eclipse I see below error

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

[image]

I am seeing above error while adding selenium jar files in eclipse.
I was trying to add selenium jar files in eclipse, I downloaded latest selenium jar file `4.15` from selenium web site.

Comment: Some users reported that a software called HP SureClick caused this error: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/the-requested-file-operation-failed-because-the-storage-policy-blocks-that-type-of-file-error-in/td-p/10320542

Comment: you should also avoid importing those "-sources" files.  Those usually cause namespace conflicts.